# php extension intl for php7.3 does not exists

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, php-extension

I upgraded the media wiki core on my server to the latest version. Then I got the information, that this version only works, if the php extension Intl is installed.

So my mission is: **Install the php extension Intl and get it running!**

What I have done so far?

1. I installed this package with the command: `apt install php-intl`. But when looking at a sample phpinfo() file, I do not see that the extension Intl is up and running. Media wiki says the same.
2. Then I started to search in web. I found, that I have to enable the extension in php.ini. So I looked in phpinfo(), what is the actual php.ini file and I removed the semicolon to get the line `extension=intl` in it.
3. Restarted apache server, but nothing changed. Then I tried to enable this mod with the command `phpenmod intl`, but then I get the response:

```
WARNING: Module intl ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.0/mods-available
WARNING: Module intl ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.0/mods-available
WARNING: Module intl ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available
WARNING: Module intl ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available
WARNING: Module intl ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available
```

4. When I try to install the intl extension specifically for php7.3 with the command: `apt install php7.3-intl`, then I get the response:

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
E: Paket php7.3-intl kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Mittels des Musters »php7.3-intl« konnte kein Paket gefunden werden.
E: Mittels regulärem Ausdruck »php7.3-intl« konnte kein Paket gefunden werden.
```

It is German, but basically it says, that there was no packet with the name php7.3-intl found.

So now, I am unable to get further and to make it running :-( I hope you can help me, because I need my media wiki up and runing quite fast again.

My system: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS

Webserver: Apache 2, it is using php7.3

Thank you very much in advance.

Best,
Viv

Comment: Try adding [Sury repo](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/) to your system and install PHP and modules from it.

Comment: intl isn't maintained anymore since 5.2.4 so these no specifically intl version for php 7.3

and try `pecl install intl` ( the most php package are installed by pecl instead of apt )

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried `pecl install intl`. It ended with the following error: 

`In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.h:34:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.c:25:
/tmp/pear/temp/intl/intl_error.h:24:40: fatal error: ext/standard/php_smart_str.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden`

So basically one file named php_smart_str.h was not found. I am searching the web for some ideas on that. Nothing found yet...